# include function in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks

Recently I have started learning codeigniter framework. I am facing a problem in including files from another folder. In my view folder, i have two folders named patient and includes. This is like below

views

```
 includes - it has two folders (front & back) - back folder has a file head.php.

 patients - it has a file patient.php
```

now I want to include head.php in patient.php.

when I use (include 'D:\XMPP\htdocs\codeigniter\application\views\includes\back\head.php'), it works.

but when I use (include '../includes/back/head.php'), it doesn't work.

how to make the 2nd option work?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this route - `includes\back\head.php`

```
<?php include VIEWPATH . "includes\back\head.php"; ?>
```

Comment: When writing an answer, it should contain a proper example together with an explanation how/why it solves what issue. As it's written now, it looks more like a comment than an answer.